# Why does this scipy.odr fit using custom jacobians segfault?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, scipy, numerical

I am trying to use [scipy.odr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) to fit measured data points to my model. While fitting without specifying jacobians works, but produces bad results for some models, I get segmentation faults when specifying my own jacobians with *some* models only.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import scipy.odr as odr

tspace = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

def fun(p, x):
    a, x0 = p
    r = a * (x - x0)**2
    return r

def param_jacobian(p, x, *args):
    a, x0 = p
    r = np.array([
        (x.T - x0)**2,
        -2*a*x0*(x.T - x0),
    ])
    return r

def value_jacobian(p, x, *args):
    a, x0 = p
    r = np.array([
        2*a*(x.T - x0),
    ])
    return r

correct = fun((0.5, 3), tspace)

p0 = (0.1, 1)

model = odr.Model(fun, fjacb=param_jacobian, fjacd=value_jacobian)
data = odr.Data(tspace, correct)

fitter = odr.ODR(data, model, beta0=p0)
fitter.set_job(0, 2)
fitter.run()
fitter.output.pprint()
```

This example crashes with a segfault on python 2.7, 64bit, scipy 0.9.0. If you switch of the use of custom jacobians by calling `fitter.set_job(0, 0)` or `fitter.set_job(0, 1)`, it works (fit results are fine in *this* example, but not in others).

Where is my mistake? Is it my mistake at all?

**Update:** I came accross that problem once again. I ran gdb and valgrind upon the fit script. gdb shows a stacktrace into `malloc_consolidate`, which is deeply called by some import attempt of a `syslog` module… seems odd to me, but I think thats irrelevant because valgrind shows the following twos times earlier, right after `param_jacobian` has been called for the first time (which is after `value_jacobian`). The segfault happens when trying to obtain the result. I suspect that the segfault is due to heap corruption and that this might be a bug in `odrpack.so`.

```
==32764== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x14239ee0, 0x14239ee0, 32)
==32764==    at 0x4A09306: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 (mc_replace_strmem.c:653)
==32764==    by 0x1B3663EB: fcn_callback (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32764==    by 0x1B3A1821: doddrv_ (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32764==    by 0x1B3A282A: dodcnt_ (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32764==    by 0x1B3A355A: dodrc_ (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32764==    by 0x1B36A452: odr (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32764==    by 0x3A41249382: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2529)
==32764==    by 0x3A412DA8F6: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (ceval.c:3967)
==32764==    by 0x3A412D89E9: builtin_apply (bltinmodule.c:195)
==32764==    by 0x3A412E03DA: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4098)
==32764==    by 0x3A412E075D: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4184)
==32764==    by 0x3A412E19A4: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3330)
```

Even later, after the `*_jacobian` functions have been called a second time:

```
==32100== Invalid read of size 8
==32100==    at 0x18189BFB: gen_output (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32100==    by 0x1818C4BA: odr (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32100==    by 0x3A41249382: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2529)
==32100==    by 0x3A412DA8F6: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (ceval.c:3967)
==32100==    by 0x3A412D89E9: builtin_apply (bltinmodule.c:195)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E03DA: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4098)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E075D: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4184)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E19A4: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3330)
==32100==    by 0x3A412DFF02: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4194)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E19A4: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3330)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E1AD1: PyEval_EvalCode (ceval.c:689)
==32100==    by 0x3A412FBD5B: run_mod (pythonrun.c:1361)
==32100==  Address 0x10207b40 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==32100==    at 0x4A0662E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==32100==    by 0xC1050FF: ??? (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so)
==32100==    by 0xC110199: ??? (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so)
==32100==    by 0x18189A7E: gen_output (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32100==    by 0x1818C4BA: odr (in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/__odrpack.so)
==32100==    by 0x3A41249382: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2529)
==32100==    by 0x3A412DA8F6: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (ceval.c:3967)
==32100==    by 0x3A412D89E9: builtin_apply (bltinmodule.c:195)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E03DA: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4098)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E075D: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4184)
==32100==    by 0x3A412E19A4: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3330)
==32100==    by 0x3A412DFF02: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4194)
```

And similar errors (`Invalid read of size 8` from within the same function) several times.

I tried `LD_PRELOAD`'ing the small memcpy replacement posted at [this (mostly unrelated) bugreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477#c38), but that didn't help.

Comment: In fact, I found that I used the wrong model. With my correct model, fitting works, but thats probably related to the fact that the correct model has one-dimensional output on two-dimensional input. I'd still like to know how to fit a function with multi-dimensional output, if that's possible at all.

Comment: I don't see how from your `fun()` you will get two dimensional output with one dimensional input. Still, I think it should be possible to fit a 1D->2D function with ODR.

Comment: @tiago You're right of course. It's not related to multiple dimensions (as said, I screwed up the model and had a big thinking mistake there) but it's certainly related to the jacobians.